# Nodejs with mysql2, promise functions in are not excuted in order

Tags: node.js, async-await, es6-promise, mysql2

In my nodejs app I need to write data into my mysql database, then create a PDF file out of this data and then send this file as an attachment in an email.

The two functions generatePDF() and sendMail() are async function and, therefore, return a promise. I am calling these two functions in connection.query(). I know that I have to use promises in order to run generatePDF() first before sendMail() is executed but I am unable to get this working.

I tried to use, without success :

- `await generatePDF()` and `await sendMail()` (with and without `async` before `function`) but this throws an error `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules`
- `generatePDF().then(sendMail())` but they are executed asynchronously
- `Promise.all([generatePDF(),(sendMail()])` but they are executed asynchronouslyi

For clarity, I only post parts of the code.

````
const mysql = require('mysql2'); // I tried mysql2/promise as well


app.post('/HSF/calculator/register', async function (request, response) {
    var params = request.body;
    //console.log('params:',params);
    connection.query('INSERT INTO client_data SET ?', params, function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) {
            throw error;
        }
        else {
                console.log('after .query(), before createOutputFile')
                var createOutputFile = `
                        SELECT
                                CONCAT("{",'"id":',
                                         JSON_OBJECT(
                                         "clientID",clientID,"name",name,"email",email,"age",age,"currentWeight",currentWeight,"weightUnit",weightUnit,"goalWeight",goalWeight,
                                         "height",height,"goalDate",goalDate,"mealsPerDay",mealsPerDay,"activityLevel",activityLevel,"eatingStyle",eatingStyle,"nutritionalRatio",
                                         nutritionalRatio,"workoutLevel",workoutLevel)
                                ,"}")
                                AS json FROM HerSoulFit.client_data
                                WHERE fileCounter = ${params.fileCounter}
                                INTO OUTFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/data_${params.fileCounter}.json';`
                        connection.query(createOutputFile, (error, results) => {
                                if (error) {
                                        throw error
                                }
                                else {
                                        response.end(JSON.stringify(results));
                                }
                        })
                        await PDF.generatePDF(params.fileCounter)
                        await nodemailer.sendMail(params.name, params.email, params.fileCounter)
                        // does not work: PDF.generatePDF(params.fileCounter).then(nodemailer.sendMail(params.name, params.email, params.fileCounter))

       });
});

```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the async keyword is in the wrong place. Remove it and change this line :

```
connection.query('INSERT INTO client_data SET ?', params, function (error, results, fields) {
```

to

```
connection.query('INSERT INTO client_data SET ?', params, async function (error, results, fields) {
```

I confirm it will be better to call sendMail when generatePDF resolve

Comment: No error is thrown but 'await sendMail()' is not executed

Comment: Perharps you have problem with nodemailer configuration, try to add a catch to sendmail and print error in console

Comment: I added a try/catch (in addition there are other console logs in that file) but I am not getting anything back. I get the last log of generatePDF() after that my server.js stops.

Comment: If your server.js hang, you should find some errors in error log file

Answer (score -1):

I believe you would have to change this line:

```js
connection.query('INSERT INTO client_data SET ?', params, function (error, results, fields)
```

to this line:

```js
await connection.query('INSERT INTO client_data SET ?', params, async function (error, results, fields)
```

This would await the connection for the post call and inside the query you can then await the anonymous function.

*Just a guess*

Comment: The await throws the error: 'SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules'

Comment: Does it give you a line and column?